# SQL reporting services report not showing date in correct format

Tags: sql-server-2005, date, formatting, reportingservices-2005

i have built a reporting services report off SQL server 2005 and am having trouble getting the date to format correctly in a stand-alone textbox.

The code i am using is as follows:

```
="Date: " & FormatDateTime(Parameters!date.Value, 2))
```

-- According to MSDN it should work off my systems culture when set to '2' however it is not.

Currently being displayed = MMDDYYYY, 
Want to display = DDMMYYYY

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Grant - I think you accepted my answer before I edited it to respect regional settings. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reports have their own Internationalisation settings - they don't use the systems.

Open your report Properties page (Click on the blank area of the report and check the Properties panel) and look at the Language settings. It will be set to English (United States). Set it to **=User!Language** to make it respect the user's regional settings.