# SSRS FormatDateTime

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Im using `=FormatDateTime(Parameters!StartDate.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)`
and its returning "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

I want to return it in this format "dd/MM/yyyy". Please help how to do it!

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975955/how-do-i-format-date-and-time-on-ssrs-report ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL reporting services report not showing date in correct format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540948/sql-reporting-services-report-not-showing-date-in-correct-format)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=Format(Parameters!StartDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Click on the reportcanvas, Press F4. Now you get the properties of the report.
There is a property called 'language'.
Choose the appropriate setting, for example NL_nl if you want dutch notation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't vote up/down due to an inadequate rep but the correct answer is that provided by henrov.  In my case, it involved setting the language to en-GB.

I did, however, have to quit SSRS; delete the compiled reports; relaunch SSRS and recompile before the change could be seen in the preview window.

Comment: Just add a comment below the answer you want to upvote, adding another "empty" answer is unhelpful.

Comment: Cheers for the -1; that helps my rep even more.  At least I now know the correct link to click.

Comment: You can also delete the *.rdl file and preview the report again. You won't get cached results then and don't have to quit VS.